# Куда вставлять файл чтобы скачать его по ссылке (Elementor)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

На сайте нужно предусмотреть скачивание файла при клике на картинку, файл всегда будет текстовый, скорее всего pdf. Конструкиция  `<a href="" download="">` готова, но вот в `href=""` я не знаю какой путь прописать, так как работаю в Elementor, а не просто в html файле. Куда файл нужно вставить и откуда идет путь, с какой папки? Или если файл добавляется в сам Wordpress то как туда вставить и указать к нему путь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам нужно загрузить ваш файл в раздел медиафайлы.
2. Скопировать ссылку на файл

[image: Ссылка]

3. Выбрать в Elementor блок html-код и вставьте туда

```
<a href="Ссылка с пункта 2" download>Скачать файл</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

загрузите просто фаил в медиабиблиотеку и просто скопируйте ссылку от туда и вставьте в елемнтор

Comment: Так не работает, так просто открывается ссылка на wordpress. Я разобрался. Нужно в корневую папку закинуть, и получится вот так site.ru/dowlands/fail.pdf а прописать нужно вот так /dowlands/fail.pdf

Comment: @ПавелЛукашевич с чего Вы взяли что так не работает и что в Вашем понимании "открывается ссылка на WordPress"?

Comment: @ПавелЛукашевич [Add a PDF Download Button using Elementor](https://www.mickthewpmentor.com.au/pdf-download-button-using-elementor/)

Answer (score 0):

необходимо загрузить файл в любое место, чтобы любой человек мог его скачать

яндекс диск.
файло обменники
или лично ваш сайт
надо обращать внимание на то чтобы он был доступен длительное время

потом в href="место /ссылка/ куда вы положили файл включая http или https"